# How prevent my side-by-side tables from overlapping?

Tags: tables, minipage, sidebyside

I have two long tables, that I want side-by-side. When I use country codes they are OK, but as I want to use country names instead, they get too wide and overlap. As far as I can see, there is still plenty of space left on the page for the tables to be side by side without overlapping. I don't need to make the tables look very nice (yet), I just need them to be readable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times]{article}
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{blablabla}
    \resizebox{0.6\textwidth}{!}{


     \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lc|lc}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{OLS} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{OLS}\tabularnewline
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Negative}\tabularnewline
    \hline 
    A very very long country name & -0.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
    A very very long country name & -0.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline

    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 

    \hfill


    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
     \centering

    \begin{tabular}{lc|lc}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{OLS} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{OLS}\tabularnewline
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Negative}\tabularnewline
    \hline 
    A very very long country name & -1.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
    A very very long country name & -0.4 & A very very long country name & -0.01\tabularnewline

    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}} 
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The tables are overlapping because you squeeze them into minipages of fixed width. Maybe the following snippet helps you to find a better solution. Notice, however, that I had to guess a document class and a preamble.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
Your original minipages were not wide enough to fit all the stuff you put there.
However, were also using a \texttt{tabular} environment, which prevented the
lines from breaking. Since you were using the \texttt{minipage} environment, I'm
wondering if you want the text to break. In that case consider
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{blablabla}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}c|p{2.5cm}c}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{OLS} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{OLS}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Negative}\tabularnewline
\hline 
A very very long country name & -0.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
A very very long country name & -0.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage} 
&
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}c|p{2.5cm}c}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{OLS} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{OLS}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Negative}\tabularnewline
\hline 
A very very long country name & -1.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
A very very long country name & -0.4 & A very very long country name & -0.01\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

If you really want to use resizebox, recall first that
\verb|\resizebox{0.6\textwidth}{!}{stuff}| scales stuff to 0.6$\times$textwidth,
which is probably not what you wanted. I'm assuming you wanted to use
\verb|\scalebox| instead. A somewhat more appropriate usage of \verb|\resizebox|
yields
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{blablabla}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{m{16cm}m{16cm}}
 \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} 
  \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}c|p{6cm}c}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{OLS} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{OLS}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Negative}\tabularnewline
\hline 
A very very long country name & -0.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
A very very long country name & -0.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage} 
& 
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}c|p{6cm}c}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{OLS} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{OLS}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Negative}\tabularnewline
\hline 
A very very long country name & -1.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
A very very long country name & -0.4 & A very very long country name & -0.01\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}% 
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

However, for the sake of readability I'd recommend not use this method. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I do not want lines to break. The solution for table 2 worked best, I now how a readable table, but I will spend some time trying to understand what is going on in your two suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

for two parallel tables in float you not need `minipage`s. for nicer text filing in  cells i suggest to use `RaggedRight` command from `ragged2e` packages. also smaller font (but not smaller than `\footnotesize`) and `tabcolsep` will be of help:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{blablabla}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small
%
\begin{tabular}[t]{R{2.5cm}c|R{2.5cm}c}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{OLS} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{OLS}   \tabularnewline
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Negative}\tabularnewline
    \hline
A very very long country name & -0.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
A very very long country name & -0.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{R{2.5cm}c|R{2.5cm}c}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{OLS} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{OLS}\tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Negative}\tabularnewline
\hline
A very very long country name & -1.00 & A very very long country name & -0.00\tabularnewline
A very very long country name & -0.4 & A very very long country name & -0.01\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**

if you like to stick both table together, than in above *mwe* replace lines

```
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{R{2.5cm}c|R{2.5cm}c}
```

with:

```
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{R{2.5cm}c|R{2.5cm}c}
```

and with use of `\footnotesize` for font size you will obtain:

[image]

however, i wonder, why you not set this tables as one in the first place?

Comment: Thank you. I honestly don't quite understand the usage of minipage, I just googled how to make to tables side-by-side, and most of the suggestions contained minipage. I will spend some more time trying to perfectionize my tables later, and study your suggestion. What if I don't want lines to break?

Comment: then replace `\hfill` after `end{tabular}` with sign %

Comment: @AnneDoe, see edit of my answer

Comment: Thank you, again. Does the % itself have any function? I thought it was just for commenting.

And you've got a very good point. I started off with two separate tables on two separate pages, and later figured out I wanted them side by side. Making one table would probably be much wiser now that I know I want them on one page.

Comment: @AnneDoe, with`%` is deleted any space after it, i.e. if it follow immediately after the first table (as is in my code above), the second table is tied to the first.